# How to bind different properties of two Classes in a Single Object?

Tags: c#, class, oop, object, asp.net-core

I have two Classes with properties and I want to add those properties to a single object.

**Product Class**

```
[Table("Product")]
class Product 
{
int ProductId {get; set;}
string ProductName {get;set}
string ProductDescription {get;set;}
decimal ProductPrice {get; set;}
}
```

**Cart Class**

```
[Table("Cart")]
class Cart 
{
int CartId {get; set;}
int Cart Quantity {get;set;}
int ProductId {get; set;}
int TotalPrice {get;set;}
}
```

I want to bind in two class properties in a single Object.

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: Can you show in pseudo code, what exactly do you want to achieve, and your reasoning behind it?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question: do you want to create a new interface and/or class `ICartProduct` with all of the properties from both `ICart` and `IProduct`?

Comment: Are you trying to create a single object that will hold all the properties of these two class? If so then please provide some more information like where are you using these two class, where are you initializing their data and where are you trying to pass the merged object

Comment: Yes I am trying to create a single object that will hold all the properties of Cart and Product. I am building an E-Commerce site. While fetching the data from Cart table which holds only foreign key ref to Product table.So binding these two class props to get the details from both the classes.